# UINavigationController popViewController bug

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, sprite-kit

I have three VC in my app A->B->C (A&B have SKView with an SKScene in them).

The following scenario should run:
 A(pressed a button)->B(played a scene, finished)->C(a few buttons and UILabels, also loads info from Game Center).
When I pop from C->A (popToRootViewController), everything works fine (although I have seen a memory leak once, I think).

The problem is when I press a button that does popViewController from C->B.

In the first time it works, B loads again, and when it comes to C the second time `UIView` animations won't work. Also when I `NSLog self.navigationController.viewControllers`, it shows (when transitioning from B->C after C was popped) that there are 2 C View Controllers- C has been created twice (it was deleted when going from C->B, then created twice)!

Consider this case:

`AViewController: 0x17683d80,`

`BViewController: 0x1c956720`

When B is loaded the second time (after popViewController called from C), and then

`"AViewController: 0x17683d80",`
    `"BViewController: 0x1c956720",`
    `"CViewController: 0x1ca49e40",`
    `"CViewController: 0x1ca4c6c0"`

When NSLog'd after C was loaded the second time. Also the app will crash if I try to go from C->B the second time (sometimes it shows a black view, sometimes crashes).

What is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without seeing your code, but I had an issue with a slow dismissal of the Modal View Controller, but setting my Scene up this way solved my issues.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    SKView *_skView;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (!_skView) {

        _skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        _skView.showsFPS = YES;
        _skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:_skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [_skView presentScene:scene];
        [self.view addSubview:_skView];
    }
}
```

The viewDidLayoutSubviews is so landscape has correct coordinates, if you in portrait just keep your original set up. The main thing is having the _skView iVar.

Comment: The problem is not a sluggish dismiss. The problem is a non dismissing (not popping!)

Comment: so the above didn't help i guess.

Comment: when you go from C to B the skView, is most likely if you aint using an iVar like above is being create again, a new instance as you noted in the log. Set up with an iVar should fix problem

Comment: yeah, just tested my modal view and every time I show it, a new instance is created (new location in memory). Which is normal for a modal view. When you go from C to B is issue - so B is the problem.